# How to populate the SQLite data from the android app to another computer's windows application in real time?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to make an android app that connected with PC at the moment.

For example,
If turned on the stopwatch from the android app, it writes the time measured on SQLite database.
The measured time is populated to the application of an another computer in real time.

Would you please suggest some ways to do this?
Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Will they be connected? the device and PC?

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize a service for this, many tutorials exist to get a JSON or XML service connected to your app. The service effectly calls a receiver or listener and executes your intent. Start with eclipse or mono and http://www.android.com/developers/ to get started.
An example of service connection exists here
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Music-Sound/simplemusicplayer/com/app/liviu/simpleMusciPlayer/musicPlayer/MusicPlayer.java.htm
You can also utilize wifi only if the app will be on your private network.